# how to get another website's meta content

Tags: php

hi i am working on a project . in this project i need another websites meta content.
here is an example

this is remote websites meta content

```
<meta content="Kültür Sanat Edebiyat Portalı. Geniş Türkçe şiir ve şair arşivi. Yarışmalar, şiir etkinlikleri, sanat haberleri. Kitaplar ile ilgili geniş ve detaylı tanıtımlar. Resim tiyatro sergi." name="description">
```

i tried php file_get_contents

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://antoloji.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

but coulnot find a way how to take only meta content (description part)
thank you for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a really useful function for this, [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) which allows you to parse the meta tags of a websites source.

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```